# WPF add datagrid row from other window

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have an add movie window:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = txtName.Text;
            string genre = txtGenre.Text;
            bool dubbed = checkBox1.IsChecked.Value;
            bool is3d = checkBox2.IsChecked.Value;
            MessageBox.Show(name + " " + genre);
            var main = new MainWindow();
            main.CallbackAddMovie(name, genre, dubbed, is3d);
            this.Close();
        }
```

And the callback:

```
   public class DataItem
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string genre { get; set; }
            public bool dubbed { get; set; }
            public bool is3d { get; set; }
        }

        public void CallbackAddMovie(string mname, string mgenre, bool mdubbed, bool mis3d)
        {
            dataGrid1.Items.Add(new DataItem { name = "Movie name2", genre = "Action", dubbed = true, is3d = true });
            dataGrid1.Items.Add(new DataItem { name = mname, genre = mgenre, dubbed = mdubbed, is3d = mis3d });
            dataGrid1.SelectAll();
        }
```

When I add a movie, I get the message boxes but the datagrid won't have the new items in it.
What is worng?

**EDIT:

Here is my datagrid creation:**

```
  var colname = new DataGridTextColumn();
            colname.Header = "Name";
            colname.Binding = new Binding("name");
            dataGrid1.Columns.Add(colname);

            var colgenre = new DataGridTextColumn();
            colgenre.Header = "Genre";
            colgenre.Binding = new Binding("genre");
            dataGrid1.Columns.Add(colgenre);

            var coldubbed = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            coldubbed.Header = "Dubbed";
            coldubbed.Binding = new Binding("dubbed");
            dataGrid1.Columns.Add(coldubbed);

            var col3d = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            col3d.Header = "3D";
            col3d.IsReadOnly = true;
            col3d.Binding = new Binding("is3d");
            dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col3d);


            // create and add two lines of fake data to be displayed, here
            dataGrid1.Items.Add(new DataItem { name = "Movie name", genre = "Action", dubbed = true, is3d = true });
```

**EDIT:**
Full project:
MainWindow.cs: 
http://pastebin.com/Xrr6DjuH
MainWindow.xaml:
http://pastebin.com/SJS4akU4
AddMovie:
http://pastebin.com/J7C5ub8N

Comment: show your xaml code for data grid, please

Comment: @agam360 dude your code is horrible. Learn MVVM. Don't use WPF as if it were winforms.

Comment: your code contradicts the ideology of WPF, but it is working code and it should work. Are you sure you call the code of creation only once?

Comment: @AntonSemenov, yes, would you like to see the whole project on paste bin?

Comment: @agam360 ok, lets take a look on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding items directly to the datagrid using `Items.Add()`, you should create a collection, like a `List<>` or `ObservableCollection<>` and assign it as the datasource of the datagrid.  Then instead of adding a new `DataItem` to the datagrid, simply add a new object to the datasource and the grid will be automatically updated.

WPF is meant to be used in a MVC pattern, and you are using it more like WinForms.

EDIT:  Here is an example that shows how WPF would work in this situation

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ObservableCollection<ListObject> _listDatasource;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _listDatasource = new ObservableCollection<ListObject>();
        listView1.ItemsSource = _listDatasource;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddWindow winAdd = new AddWindow();
        winAdd.AddItem += new AddItemHandler(winAdd_AddItem);
        winAdd.Show();
    }

    void winAdd_AddItem(object sender, ListObject itemToAdd)
    {
        _listDatasource.Add(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
        <ListView Height="163" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,56,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" >
            <ListView.View>

                <GridView x:Name="gridList" >
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colValue"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ListValue}" Header="Value" />

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Open Add Window" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,27,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
```

AddWindow.xaml

```
 <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,71,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Label Content="Add this:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,46,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="Add it" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,114,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
```

AddWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public delegate void AddItemHandler(object sender, ListObject itemToAdd);

    public partial class AddWindow : Window
    {
        public event AddItemHandler AddItem;
        public AddWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListObject itemToAdd = new ListObject();
            itemToAdd.ListValue = textBox1.Text;
            AddItem(this, itemToAdd);
        }
    }
```

ListObject.cs

```
 public class ListObject
    {
        private string _listValue;

        public string ListValue
        {
            get { return _listValue; }
            set { _listValue = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to create something quick and dirty (this is the first time using wpf). why isn't my code working? and can you give an example of yours? (also I think that my code might not work because it is executed from another form)

Comment: Sharing data between two different forms is the same thing as sharing data between two different classes.  The 'quick and dirty' solution is the one I gave you.  Once you become familiar with WPF, you will understand what I mean.

Comment: Is there any exmaple of such binding?