# How can I add row to datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row, addition

I am very new to wpf. I am looking for some equivalent for:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sNazwa, 1, opakowanie, cena, sWartoscNetto, sVAT, sWartoscBrutto);
```

I know that I should use

```
mainwindow.dataGrid1.Items.Add()
```

but how can I define a row I want to add here?

**EDIT**

I think I should elaborate a bit on what I plan to achieve.
I am rewriting a program I made in WinForms. It makes offers for clients. It has a gridview in winforms that has a list of products for my client. In secon window I have a gridform connected to sql database. By double click on a row, some of data from the row should be transfered to mainwindow datagrid (but not the whole row). In mainwindow datagrid user should be able to edit cells, move rows (up and down), sort and delete rows. Will List<> let me do all this things? I tried to use your solution to add a row using List and it works (but I struggle to send data from second window), but still I wonder if it will let me do al this things I want later on.

**EDIT**
This works:

```
public class Produkt
{
  public string Nazwa { get; set;}
  public string Opakowanie { get; set; }
  public string Ilosc { get; set; }
  public string Cena { get; set; }
  public string WartoscNetto { get; set; }
  public string VAT { get; set; }
  public string WartoscBrutto { get; set; }
}

public List<Produkt> DodajProdukty()
{
  List<Produkt> produkt = new List<Produkt>();
  produkt.Add(new Produkt() { Nazwa = "test", Opakowanie = "test", Ilosc = "1", Cena = "test", WartoscNetto = "test", WartoscBrutto = "test" });
  return produkt;

}


private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  dataGrid1.ItemsSource = DodajProdukty();
}
```

but how can I add a row from different window?

thanks,

Comment: create a proper ViewModel / Data Model and bind to that. WPF is not winforms. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: @HighCore - Do you mean that I should for example make some datatable, bind it to datagrid and then add row to datatable?

Comment: No, I mean you should create a strongly typed object model, and then create a collection of these objects to bind to. `DataTable` is just a glorified `Dictionary<string,object>` which forces you to all sorts of magic-string based stuff and constant casting. WPF supports DataBinding to CLR objects.

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka You can just bind a List containing your items. Properties of your objects will be your DataGrid's columns ; or manually define columns with a Binding on each.

Comment: @Etienne I think I more or less understand. Do you have any example?

Comment: @EtienneFesser Did you mean it like this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/

Comment: same question can found at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251327/wpf-datagrid-add-new-row

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out earlier by [HighCore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643085/highcore), you should do that by using a list (collection) of objects, you want to display in your DataGrid. This is where **Binding** comes in.

There are several tutorials and guides out there but you may have some questions or need some hints to carry on.

At this moment it'd good to know that some things are quite different while others are not when passing over to WPF. You may read [this](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) article written by [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey). It was a really great read and helped me leaving WinForms as framework behind.

If you are at the point where you'd say that you are ready to implement your first **MVVM** sample, you should really take a look into concepts such as **Binding**, **Events**, **Commands** and how it works first.

In this particular case you wouldn't need the functionality to notify the View about any changes that have been made since you stated above, that the data won't change. However the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't necessary at all here but you should consider using it in though.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this worked perfectly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15749641/2186128

Now I need to learn what all that mean :)